# Is Swift code turned into optmized Objective-C code under the hood?

Tags: ios, swift

I couldn't manage to find an answear to this question. Is Swift just an Objective-C wrapper, where Swift code is turned into objective-c when the code compiles?

Comment: No, it isn't. (if it was, it couldn't be faster than Objective-C.) - BTW, you don't have to read a lot to get this information. Just read the introduction on developer.apple.com. It clearly states that Swift is an LLVM-based language.

Comment: @user3477950 Not to argue your main point, but a Swift-to-ObjC compiler might still improve performance. The code a compiler outputs does not necessarily resemble anything a human might write, even when optimizing by hand. It's true that the optimal Objective-C code could technically also be typed up by a human, but claiming that a human can or will frequently (let alone always) find that code is as fallacious as the [sufficiently smart compiler](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?SufficientlySmartCompiler) argument.

Comment: @delnan I don't deny that compilers are often better at optimizing code than humans, and therefore compiler-generated Objective-C may be faster than hand-written Objective-C. However, without further annotations, Objective-C cannot be faster than Objective-C, by definition. Apple did not state that "Swift is faster than hand-written Objective-C". They claimed that "Swift is faster than Objective-C".

Comment: Yes in that many classes bridge to or extend Objective-C classes and every class is a `Class` and supports the NSObject protocol, no in that Swift methods are not Objective-C methods and a lot of efficiency is probably gained by that alone.  There's probably a lot more that will be said by the community after the NDA is lifted.

Comment: @user3477950 What Apple claims in their very popular presentation (as opposed to documentation and technical references) is of little interest for technical discussion since it's at least 50% marketing. And no, Obj-C doesn't magically get faster than Obj-C, but *Swift* behaves rather differently from Obj-C (e.g. there is static dispatch for methods), a Swift->Obj-C *does* have extra "annotations" (information) by virtual of reading Swift code rather than Obj-C code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, it is made into **llvm bytecode** or -as pointed out by delnan- as it called today **llvm bitcode**

"[The new term is used] partly to break association with bytecode as employed by traditional virtual machines (because LLVM IR is very much different from that)"

Comment: FYI The usual term these days is "bitcode", partly to break association with *bytecode* as employed by traditional virtual machines (because LLVM IR is very much different from that).